# HP Wolf Security Zbook G9 laptop

Tags: boot, uefi

I have a bootable USB stick that contains the try bootable image of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS as distributed by Ubuntu.  Normally, after the try, I do a full install as the try verifies that Ubuntu can "see" the hardware.  On an HP Zbook G9, following the HP service manual, I removed the HP supplied MS Win unbooted SSD, and replaced it with a new unformatted Crucial SSD.  The G9 has "Wolf Security".  There is no menu to boot from the USB drive and there is mechanism to boot and eliminate Wolf Security from the machine.  Do I need to first boot into the supplied MS Win SSD, make changes in the BIOS, and then try to boot the USB stick with 22.04.2 ?  Will it boot?  What changes must be made?  If I `dd` as root from a working USB based Ubuntu system with a UEFI secure boot to the unused SSD (accessed via a USB to SSD external attachment device) will that work?  Say that the working system is /dev/sda and the USB attached SSD appears as /dev/sdd, then I would do a full `dd` from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb that should include all of the partitions including UEFI boot (or is even more required?).  If a "key" is required to boot, how does one discover the magic key?  Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to TS. I don't like disabling secure boot. Copying Ubuntu images did not work for me. Providing custom path to image does not exist in my UEFI settings.

Disclaimer: I am reproducing the steps by memory. I might be missing some steps. I don't know all the consequences. I take no responsibility for bricking/otherwise damaging anyone's laptop.

My config:

1. Laptop: HP EliteBook 835 13 inch G10 Notebook PC
2. System BIOS: V83 Ver.01.03.02 09/20/2023
3. OS: Windows 11 (pre-installed), Ubuntu 23.04 (installed later on)

This is what worked for me:

1. Enter "HP Computer Setup" via F10
2. Security - Create BIOS Administrator Password - Enable Admin password
3. Main - Save Changes and Exit

- Rebooting...

4. Enter "HP Computer Setup"
5. Security - Secure Boot Configuration - Untick/Disable "Secure Boot"
6. Main - Save Changes and Exit

- Rebooting...

---

- Install Ubuntu
- Rebooting...

---

7. Enter "HP Computer Setup"
8. Security - Tick/Enable "Clear Secure Boot Keys"
9. Main - Save Changes and Exit

- Rebooting...
- Enter confirmation code shown on display

10. Enter "HP Computer Setup"
11. Security - Secure Boot Configuration - Tick/Enable "Secure Boot"
12. Main - Save Changes and Exit

- Rebooting...

13. Enter "HP Computer Setup"
14. Security - Tick/Enable "Enable MS UEFI CA key"
15. Main - Save Changes and Exit

- Rebooting...

(optional)

16. Enter "HP Computer Setup"
17. Security - Create BIOS Administrator Password - Enable Admin password - Type current password - Type empty password to disable it
18. Main - Save Changes and Exit

- Rebooting...

Result: Windows boots (with Bitlocker and TPM support enabled), Ubuntu boots.

Comment: @banderlog013 Could you elaborate please? Step 9 is not enough. At least step 1 is required. I can't understand how just saving changes without making any changes in the first place resolves the issue.

Comment: @banderlog013 thank you. Do I understand correctly that after only step 1, 8, and 9 you still have "Secure Boot" enabled in BIOS and also Bitlocker and TPM support are enabled in Windows?

Comment: UPD: I was wrong, all 12 steps are necessary, sorry for misleading

Comment: @banderlog013 No worries, thank you for trying out proposed solution and confirming its usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

In the USA, HP provides a toll-free (no charge) telephone number to Technical Support (TS).  On the bottom of the machine in low contrast small print is a serial number.  Once that was provided, the TS person walked me through the procedure.  Note that I already had downloaded the HP service and repair manual for this machine, had removed and stored the 1 TByte SSD that contains the HP installed MS Windows 11 environment, and installed a new Crucial 4 Tbyte SSD.  For those who may find a URL on the web showing the procedure used to open the machine and change components (the various locations, etc., are correct in the video) beware:  the person doing the disassembly was not using a grounded antistatic mat nor was she/he wearing a grounded wrist strap.  I use these things plus antistatic tools where the entire assembly is grounded to the building mains ground (earth).  After HP TS walked me through the procedure to access a USB memory stick (thumb drive) boot, upon which `Startup Disk Creator` has installed the "stock" 22.04.2 ISO image, the USB memory stick booted (with the HP Wolf Security splash screen being displayed prior to boot) and the try to verify hardware support and then the install completed without issues (I am using the HP Zbook G9 to post this).  Two comments:  the G9 is certified for 20.04 but 22.04.2 works fine; supposedly, the (proprietary) Nvidia package has issues on these machines under 22.04 (the HP TS person provided me with HP document).  I installed the Nvidia package (the one that had *tested* listed for the package) and it is working without issue.  I need the full functionality of the Nvidia driver and configuration tools.